# IntelliJ IDEA using wrong schema to validate xml file

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an XML file with multiple namespaces and schema locations. I recently needed to update one of the schema locations to reflect a new library being used and updated attributes for some of the XML tags.

After changing the `xsi:schemaLocation` information to reflect the new version, it continues to validate the file against the old schema.

I added the (old) schema in quesiton to `Preferences -> Schemas & DTDs -> Ignored Schemas and DTDs`.

I have used `File -> Invalidate Caches....` and then `Invalidate and Restart` without selecting any of the boxes, but this hasn't changed anything - when it restarts, it continues to use the old version.

It appears to be using a version of the (old) schema that is actually in a library that *used* to be available in this module, but that library isn't included in the module anymore (as verified by looking at `command-; -> modules`) while a library with the new schema is. Either way - the URL doesn't point to that library directly. And I've confirmed that the new URL returns a schema.

I'm not even sure where else to begin looking for where it is getting the old schema, how to clear out knowledge of the old library, or how to find where that old library may be referenced anymore in other modules that might be pulled in.

IntelliJ Version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.6008.13, built on July 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.15+10-b2043.56 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

OS Version:

```
macOS Monterey
Version 12.5.1
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
Processor 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
```

Example XML file (before):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thing:base 
       xmlns:thing="http://www.example.org/schema/thing"
       xmlns:foo="http://www.example.org/schema/foo"
       xmlns:bar="http://www.example.org/schema/bar"
       xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema/bar"
       xmlns:baz="http://www.example.org/schema/baz"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.example.org/schema/thing 
         http://www.example.org/schema/thing/example-thing-2.0.xsd
         http://www.example.org/schema/foo 
         http://www.example.org/schema/foo/example-foo-2.0.xsd
         http://www.example.org/schema/bar 
         http://www.example.org/schema/bar/example-bar-2.0.xsd
         http://www.example.org/schema/baz
         http://www.example.org/schema/baz/example-baz-2.0.xsd
       ">

  <bar:snark boojum="true"/>

</thing:base>
```

Example XML file (after):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thing:base 
       xmlns:thing="http://www.example.org/schema/thing"
       xmlns:foo="http://www.example.org/schema/foo"
       xmlns:bar="http://www.example.org/schema/bar"
       xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema/bar"
       xmlns:baz="http://www.example.org/schema/baz"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.example.org/schema/thing 
         http://www.example.org/schema/thing/example-thing-2.0.xsd
         http://www.example.org/schema/foo 
         http://www.example.org/schema/foo/example-foo-2.0.xsd
         http://www.example.org/schema/bar 
         http://www.example.org/schema/bar/example-bar-3.0.xsd
         http://www.example.org/schema/baz
         http://www.example.org/schema/baz/example-baz-2.0.xsd
       ">

  <bar:snark vorpal-blade="snick" boojum="true"/>

</thing:base>
```

In this example:

- I have updated the schema location for `http://www.example.org/schema/bar` from `example-bar-2.0.xsd` to `example-bar-3.0.xsd` and added the new attribute `vorpal-blade` to the `bar:snark` tag.
- The editor has marked the `vorpal-blade` attribute in red with the error "Attribute vorpal-blade is not allowed here".
- Clicking on the `blade:snark` tag and pressing `command-B` opens a schema file from the old library for example-bar that has the 2.0 version (judging by the file name).

Any thoughts about where to begin looking to solve this or, even better, just get it to use the right schema?